# Fix Checkmarx XSS Vulnerabilities exprees js

Tags: node.js, express, xss, checkmarx

I always see checkmarx XSS Vulnerabilities in exprees router, Not sure what to use other function to fix it.I used express validator but no luck so far.

```
  const express = require("express");

const router = express.Router();
const { body, validationResult } = require("express-validator");

router.post(
  `/testData`,
  body("empName").trim().escape().not().isEmpty(),
  async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
     //getting checkmarx xss reflected vulnerability at req.body
      const callTags = req.body
      const errors = validationResult(req);
      if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
      }
      res.status(response.statusCode).json(''hello);
    } catch (ex) {
      
      next(ex);
    }
  }
);
module.exports = router;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Utilize "sanitizers" that Checkmarx recognizes such as the use of templating engines like [HandleBarsJS](https://handlebarsjs.com/) where your response will be output escaped

```
<p>Hello, {{empName}}</p>
```

Comment: this is server side code, also I used below code but still it is showing XSS issue,see code below
                  
 const calltags= sanitizer.sanitize(JSON.stringify(req.body))
    // this also shows Reflected vulnerability